# Forcing Zoom to fill screen on android tablet

Tags: android, zooming, tablet

I have an application not really designed for the tablets. However it works sufficiently well in zoom to fill screen mode. Is there a way to force an application to only be displayed in "zoom to fill screen" mode on android?

Answer (score 1):

See the document on [Screen Compatibility Mode](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screen-compat-mode.html).

> An application can also explicitly declare that it does not support large screens such that screen compatibility mode is always enabled and the user cannot disable it.

And more detail:

> If your application is functionally broken when resized for large screens and you want to force users into screen compatibility mode (rather than simply providing the option), you can use the android:largestWidthLimitDp attribute:

```
<supports-screens android:largestWidthLimitDp="320" />
```

Note that this is only when targeting 3.2 or higher. The zooming screen compatibility mode is only available on 3.2 and higher.